# How to find field width of a table in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao

In Access `DAO.TablDef` has a function `CreateField(Name,Type,Size)` I am looking for the size of an existing table field. I have a table column of type `db_text` and has a size of 6. 
[image]
`DAO recordset` has a `fields` class. I can find field type with it but not field size yet. I tried DefinedSize, NumericScale and ActualSize. Anyone knows how to find field size? Thanks

```
Dim dars As Dao.Recordset

Set dars = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TableName")

debug.print dars.Fields("FieldName").Type

debug.print dars.Fields("FieldName").DefinedSize
debug.print dars.Fields("FieldName").NumericScale
debug.print dars.Fields("FieldName").ActualSize

dars.Close
Set dars = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Size` property contains the field size:

```
debug.print dars.Fields("FieldName").Properties!Size
```